# Entity Framework Core 3.x Database first design where the database was designed without foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am working with a database that was designed 10 or so years ago not using foreign key constraints.  We are currently looking to upgrade our software to a more unified solution using EF Core.  I really tried selling the company on fixing the foreign key issue but it would require a lot more drastic switch over over and they are hoping we can keep the current solution and switch over pieces at a time.

After doing some testing with EF Core I found that selecting data and using the Attributes to specify foreign keys allowed EF Core to select data correctly based on those relationships.  However, it does not handle the foreign key constraints when inserting, updating, or deleting.  As I've tried to research the problem I'm finding that EF Core is likely relying on SQL Server to handle the insert, update, and delete constraints and therefore ignores the EF Core attributes for these operations.

I've tried using the ModelBuilder to specify the .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade) and the best EF seems to do is update the reference to NULL but never throw a foreign key constraint exception.

I suppose my question is this:

Is there anyway Entity Framework Core can handle foreign key constraints directly without having foreign keys setup in the SQL Database?  For example, if I try and delete a row in EF Core that has a relationship is there a way EF Core can deny the deletion, Or if there is an insert but the id does not exist in the table it's referencing can it deny the insert.  And only use the Property Attribute [ForeignKey] or the model builder to specify the foreign key?

Comment: If you can't change the db model in a landslide fashion, what *can* you do in the database schema? Can you add stored procedures and/or views?

Comment: This particular question is more focused on whether or not Entity Framework can handle foreign key constraints without them being configured in SQL.  I've tested a bunch of different ways and can't seem to get the same results as when the keys configured in SQL.  My results have me thinking that EF Core relies on SQL Server to manage the constraints for insert/update/delete.  However, I am wondering if I am missing a feature or configuration.  I am struggling to find a direct answer online so I am hoping someone might know the answer here.

Comment: You won't ever get EF to check FK constraints out of the box. As you correctly noticed, EF relies on the database to complain when an FK constraint is violated. But you could write stored procedures to do CUD actions and call them in EF as raw SQL or even map them to the model by using EF6. Alternatively, you could create views that joins a table to a reference so that it doesn't return data when the reference doesn't exist.

Comment: That is what I thought. I will likely try extension methods and reflection to get what I need to create a query for a key check.  I appreciate you taking the time.  I've never actually posted on stackoverflow before but I think your comment fits the answer.  Does it need to be posted as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is not designed to guard database integrity. EF's stance on validation is largely: do it yourself. Increasingly so, as they removed `IValidatableObject` support in EF core. But I actually think this is a sound approach.

So you have to do it yourself. But checking integrity violations is something developers should do anyway, even when foreign key constraints are present, because you don't want to trouble users with raw database exceptions --nor try to translate them into something more palatable. The constraints are just a final catch (which is esp. useful in cases of high concurrency). So in fact, the only thing you miss out on is this final catch. Life isn't that bad.

There is a way to mitigate this lack somewhat. You must be able to create views though.

The idea is to create an updateable view that selects all fields from the original table and inner joins with all *required* foreign keys. The entity is mapped to this view. If an insert or update is done in this view, you'll get an exception because EF encounters an unexpected number of modified rows.

Here's an example:

Database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ClubID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Club](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MemberView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT m.ID, m.Name, m.CLubID, c.Name AS ClubName
FROM dbo.Member m
INNER JOIN dbo.Club c ON m.ClubID = c.ID
```

Classes:

```cs
public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClubID { get; set; }
    public Club Club { get; set; }

    // Fake FK constraint by computed field that won't be found if reference ID doesn't match.
    public string ClubName { get; set; } 
}

public class Club
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Explicit mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
    .Property(m => m.ClubName).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().ToTable("MemberView");
modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().ToTable("Club");
```

The essential part here is mapping `ClubName` as `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate`.

Now deliberately insert a member with a non-existent club id:

```cs
using (var db = new MyContext(connectionString))
{
    db.Clubs.Add(new Club { ID = 1, Name = "Medalist Golf Club" });
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new MyContext(connectionString))
{
    db.Members.Add(new Member { ID = 1, Name = "Tiger Woods", ClubID = 2 });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Because of this `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` mappping, EF will add a `SELECT` to the `INSERT` to get database-generated values.

```sql
  INSERT INTO [MemberView] ([ID], [ClubID], [Name])
  VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
  SELECT [ClubName]
  FROM [MemberView]
  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = @p0;
```

This fails because club `2` doesn't exist and the view doesn't return a row. EF will throw an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)". It's not the same as an FK violation, but at least this offers a way to do an insert and integrity check in one atomic transaction.